# Any Solidity-based sparse merkle tree implemenations in production?

Tags: layer-2, merkleization

It looks like sparse Merkle trees are useful for proofs in L2 systems. When looking around, a number of projects can be found that implement sparse Merkle trees to authenticate state or account trees.

For security reasons, I'm interested in an audited version of a sparse Merkle tree. Is there a sparse Merkle tree implementation in Solidity that has been running and managing a significant amount of value in production on the Ethereum mainnet? If so, is its implementation open source e.g. on GitHub?

Answer (score 2):

The [ETH 2 deposit contract](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/34fc0a5d09fae6649e0c6ac7a0cb09ff5a999957/solidity_deposit_contract/deposit_contract.sol#L80) implements a sparse Merkle tree that holds [$14B of Ether](https://etherscan.io/address/0x00000000219ab540356cbb839cbe05303d7705fa) at the time of writing this answer.